# Angular - RxJS debounceTime takes too long

Tags: angular, performance, rxjs, observable

I have a debounce time of 500ms set on a form control valueChanges event. The issue is that instead of emitting value after 500ms, the value is emitted after 2-3 seconds and this is a real performance issue in the application.
How can a improve this? I checked this by logging the date before the debounceTime in the pipe operator and after it and this is what I get:

```
before debounce Tue Dec 14 2021 15:51:07 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
after debounce Tue Dec 14 2021 15:51:10 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)
```

The code:

```
this.projectAutoCompleteControl.valueChanges.pipe(
            tap(() => console.log('before debounce', new Date())),
            debounceTime(500),
            tap(() => console.log('after debounce', new Date()))
)
```

Comment: That's really weird :). Could you make a stackblitz demo that replicates the issue?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot reproduce this in a stackblitz. it seems that this happens only in my application. I have the same issue even if I use debounceTime(1). I don't know what can cause this.

Comment: when you stop writing in your input it stays 3 seconds to emit?

Comment: Probably is a performance issue with other components in the page? Are you debouncing more inputs? or there are some other components doing stuff in the page?

Comment: @FatehMohamed yes

Comment: @DiegoBascans yes, I have quite a few autocomplete on the screen. this component is something used as a filter for a table.

Comment: when you subscribe to valueChanges? are you subscribing severals times? you unsubscribe when destroy the component?

Comment: I don't subscribe to it. I use this in the template using the async pipe but I do this initialization in OnInit.

Comment: This is very weird. You could try using browser performance tab to see if there is something weird happening. You could also try using `performance.now()` API instead of date for more precision. Is it always exactly the same duration no matter what debounce time you enter?

Comment: This is happening to me as well. I have an input form control, with a debounceTime set to 500. the first input takes 3336ms, second input takes 2672ms, third takes 1678ms, and then fourth and beyond takes the correct amount of time. I can't seem to reproduce this though on stackblitz.